# Find Spell cards self banish or cards banish spell in grave

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I'm using a "Gishki Hieratic Deck" and I find this deck has a big weakness which  is some cards like [D.D. Crow](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/D.D._Crow) can ruin my deck by banishing my [Gishki Aquamirror](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Gishki_Aquamirror) in the GY.

Luckily, I have found [Parallel Selection](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Parallel_Selection), but now the problem is it only usable in a few special situation, so now I want some cards that could banish other spell card in my GY to do something useful or some spell cards could Self banish.

One more thing is I only play with friends and we have a rule that we only accept cards before 2015, you guys can check when the card out [here](https://www.db.yugioh-card.com/yugiohdb/card_search.action).

Comment: So, if your problem is that opp may banish your cards, won't you want cards that return banished  to your grave instead?... or you do want spell cards that can banish or autobanish to do something, that you could use?

Comment: If you could suggest some card that return banished spell cards to grave, it could be good, but as i said the only card i've found is "Parallel Selection" and it would be useless in normal situation so i need some other cards to make this card useable.

Answer (score 1):

First I suggets you check [this](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Returns_banished_cards_to_the_Graveyard) link on YGO Wikia, which mentions several cards that return banished cards to the GY.

Now, what you ask it a bit unclear (you want cards like Parallel Return or cards that banish spells?), but I assume it's the former, as Parallel Return is your only alternative so far.

Sorry to say this but **there seems to be no other card that can return spells from the banished zone**, and even less before 2015. I searched by several keywords in a couple good engines (one neat engine is YGO Pro's where you can search by card text), and only Parallel Return came out.

One card that came to mind is [Spellbook of Eternity](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Spellbook_of_Eternity) and does exactly that, but it only works for Spellbook cards.

To be honest most cards I've found can only return *monsters* to the GY, and not spells or traps, so Parallel Selection could be one of the few options you got. Now, cards that do this that may be useful for you still that I recall are:

- [Miracle Dig](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Miracle_Dig): «*If 5 or more of your monsters are currently removed from play, return 3 of them to the Graveyard*». Useful to return monsters to the GY (only monsters though). This is an old card so surely before 2015.
- [Burial from a Different Dimension](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Burial_from_a_Different_Dimension): «*Select up to 3 removed from play monsters, and return them to their owners' Graveyards.*». Great card, is also quick-play. It is also before 2015, but again only useful for monsters.

Now, if D.D. Crow is giving you trouble try countering it with [Debunk](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Debunk):

> Negate the activation of an Effect Monster's effect that activates in the hand or in the Graveyard, and remove it from play.

Also, if you want to prevent cards from bein banished you can play [Imperial Iron Wall](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_Iron_Wall); one widely used card on side decks.

Sorry that there is no card (apparently) that can help you here, but will add any other I recall that might be useful on this scenario.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but there is some problem: 1. Spellbook seem not fit in Gishki Hieratic Deck  2.I dont have problem with banished monster

Comment: @Doomlucifer of course, that's why I said that it only works for Spellbook. As my answer said, **seems that besides Parallel Selection there are no other options that do what you want** (and the 2015+ restriction). I included other cards with similar effects with the hopes that they may be useful for someone... if I remember or find one for spells that I missed (hardly) I'll post here, but seems that you will have better chances in countering cards that banish your spells, instead of trying to brine them back.

Comment: im sry, because i dont know how to 'enter' in comment section and after 2 edit the page not let me edit anymore but here is the 3rd problem : I've use Debunk but it became dead draw most of the time or come too late :((, trying to use "pleaguespreader zombie" with "imperial Iron Wall"

Comment: @Doomlucifer how many copies of debunk? Usually you want to use those only against decks that actually have dd crow, eff veiler, etc. Imperial iron wall could work, interesting combo that one with plaguespreader btw ;)

Comment: @Doomlucifer also, of you have new questions perhaps they are better fit for a new post if you consider it so